# Retrieve String out of addValueEventListener Firebase

Tags: android, string, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to receive a string from `addValueEventListener()` method I use to resell the data from the database Firebase. The data arrive correctly.

But when certain to get the string out of that method to use it in another, it returns nothing.

You have tips?

I already tried putExtras and also create a method on purpose but it did not work.

```
final DatabaseReference mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user-daily").child(getUid()).child("2017-Year");
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            final DailyItem dailyItem = data.getValue(DailyItem.class);
            labels.add(dailyItem.mese);



        }
        title.setText(labels.get(position));

        a = title.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"database error",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

//this return null... why?
String title = a;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time you run `title = a`, the `onDataChange` method hasn't been called yet. Set some breakpoints in a debugger to verify this, it's key to understanding how asynchronous loading works.

The solution is to reframe your problem from "first get the object, then do blabla with the title" to "start getting the object; once the object is available, do blabla with the title".

In code this translates to:

```
final DatabaseReference mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user-daily").child(getUid()).child("2017-Year");
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            final DailyItem dailyItem = data.getValue(DailyItem.class);
            labels.add(dailyItem.mese);



        }
        title.setText(labels.get(position));

        // Do blabla with the title
        String title = title.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"database error",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Many developers new to Firebase (and other modern web APIs, as they all work this way) struggle with this problem. So I recommend you also check out their questions and answers:

- [Cannot access firebaseObjectObservable outside of set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127888/cannot-access-firebaseobjectobservable-outside-of-set/42128000#42128000)
- [Android Firebase get value of child without DataChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278312/android-firebase-get-value-of-child-without-datachange/41285337#41285337)
- [Value of a global variable is reset after it is initialised in ValueEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407194/value-of-a-global-variable-is-reset-after-it-is-initialised-in-valueeventlistene/41409942#41409942)
- [can't get values out of ondatachange method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456650/cant-get-values-out-of-ondatachange-method/38460676#38460676)
- [ArrayList not updating inside onChildAdded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464918/arraylist-not-updating-inside-onchildadded-function/39472821#39472821)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener/33204705#33204705)
- and most others in [this list of search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-database%5d%5bandroid%5d%20user%3a209103%20asynchronous)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This, however, does not solve my problem because I still can not bring out this string. I will watch the applications that you left me. thank you.

Comment: You're trying to make asynchronous code synchronous. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener/33204705#33204705

Comment: thanks understand! I will look the answer in the link you gave me later, I thank you. a last well, just a guess. if I except in a given local proveninete from Firebase, for example with a shared preference, then I would be able to retrieve it outside the method?

Comment: That would allow it to be accessed in other places, but so would declaring `title` as a field on the activity. it will however *not* change *when* you can access it: the value is only accessible *after* the `onDataChange` has fired.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick which does it. It would be easy to do so if you have less data to retrieve from ValueEventListener.
Inside the `onDataChange()`, use a setText to set the required value in it. Keep the visibility of this text view as "Gone". Then retrieve using getText outside the ValueEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the string from method `addValueEventListener` in viewmodel or any other network call, it is recommended to use the either `MutableLiveData<T>` or `LiveData<T>` and observe the same in your activity. Observer will observe the changes, and as soon as string got filled up, the observer method will automatically give you string which you are looking.

You need to create reference variable for the `LiveData<T> reference_variable` wherever your `addValueEventLister` is located and set its value in your `addValueEventListener`.

And then in your viewmodel create the returning value function like below...
Observe this function in your activity and you will have your string.

```
public MutableLiveData<TotalRunsWicketsAndData> getDisplayableDetails() {
        return observableLiveData;
 }
```

I am using `MutableLiveData` here.

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the whole list by using **GenericTypeIndicator**. Follow the official guide on [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator)