# Firebase: Getting specific field from a node based on field in another node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been googling from 3 hours now but have not been able to either phrase the search term correctly or there are no good solutions for it. I am using firebase for my android app. It has a structure like following:
[image: firebase db]
The upper one is comments node

I have just displayed the comments using listview.

```
commentRef1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments").child(postKey1);
        commentRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        comment1=ds.getValue(Comment.class);
                        arrayList.add(comment1);
                    }
                    commentList.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

But as with every relational database, I am trying to save just id or uid in comments(table) or node(rather than whole username).

**But, now I am having PROBLEM querying or DISPLAYING USERNAME while displaying comments from the users node (i.e display name) as uid only is saved in comments node.**

I found some of the methods like doing nested oneventlistener and so on but little bit confused with the complications and effort need for it.
It would have been simple query or nested select in any sql languages.

Can anybody help?  How can i retrieve username or specific value in that query. I saw many storing the while username in comments table. I don't think it is right approach.

Comment: Note that duplicating data is completely normal in NoSQL database. If you're new to that, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: are you able  to get user id who commented on that post.?

Answer (score 2):

To get the full_name, you need to do the following:

```
 DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
commentRef1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments").child(postKey1);
    commentRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String userid=ds.child("uid").getValue().toString();
                   ref.child("Users").orderByKey().equalTo(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                      String fullname=dataSnapshot.child("full_name").getValue().toString();
                     }
                      @Override
                     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                          }
                       });    
                  }
              }
          }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

You can use nested listener, I guess you want the user to type the comment then click on a button and creates a node for the comment with a uid,post_id,comment.

Then you want to retrieve the comment to display it with the information, so the datasnapshot will be on `Comments/postKey1` then you can retrieve the information there(including the uid), then use `orderByKey().equalTo(userid)` to be able to retrieve the fullname of the user from the node `Users`

To avoid all of this just add the `fullname` in the `Comments` node instead of the `userid`

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

Comment: Thanks. Ya I was trying to avoid nested datasnap listeners. Anyways, that was giving me a null reference error so changed a little bit. It is giving me full name but set function (setUsername) is not working if we put it inside second eventlistener does not work...I am sure it is entering into second listener, as logcat is showing the fullname but setname function works if i put outside the second eventlistener but does not work if it is inside second one, as follows...

Comment: for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
.....comment1.setComment(ds.child("comment").getValue().toString());
//comment1.setUsername("user name1"); works
 userRef.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String fullname=dataSnapshot.child("full_name").getValue().toString();
                                Log.w("fullname", fullname);
                   comment1.setUsername(fullname);//doesnot work
                            }

Comment: I tried making fullname as a global variable and tried accessing outside that second listener...didn't work
 Log.w("fullname", fullname);

Comment: add fullname as global variable but retrieve it and use it inside the second listener and not outside, also change the `addValueEventListener`'s to `addSingleValueEventListener`

Comment: I tried that earlier didn't work   comment1=new Comment();
comment1.setComment(ds.child("comment").getValue().toString());
   //comment1.setUsername("user name1"); //works
 userRef.child(userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        fullname=dataSnapshot.child("full_name").getValue().toString();
                                comment1.setUsername(fullname); //not working
                            }
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

Comment: yes it is working. Setting inside that second listener does not work...setting above it in first listener works but off course there i do not have fullname

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168808/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-thegooooogle).

Comment: there is no error at all...but it does not get set...nothing appears for that textbox....other things are working as I say if i set it in first listener it is working....

Comment: If it helps  https://i.imgur.com/kuC4fde.png but since the same thing is working if put in first listener so may not be problem in other place...

Comment: do it as in the answer, retrieve the uid and then do orderBykey().equalTo(userid) instead of child(userid)

Comment: ya when i did that i got this error   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference thats why i changed it

Comment: are you using AddSingleValueEventListener in the two listeners first and second, not only second

Comment: Thanks for taking time. Yes I have been done it. Still null ref error. Please see the latest changes in this image. And also in the comment inside the comment 
https://i.imgur.com/loYVMvs.png

Comment: okay add a for loop `for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){ String fullname=datas.child("full_name").getValue().toString();` inside the second listener now it will work

Comment: Yes the error is gone but still comment1.setUsername(fullname); is username is not working. outputing full name in logcat is working and showing the name. The problem from the first post is comment1.setUsername(fullname); not working inside the second listener and working inside first listener...even comment1.setUsername("sometext"); inside second listener is not working which i think is really strange. But if it is in first listener it works....we are almost back to where we started now

Comment: in the second listener write `comment1=new Comment()`

Comment: Declaring it inside is giving me, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.research.xxxxxx.Comment.getUsername()' on a null object reference.....that is on this line  String name=getItem(position).getUsername();

Comment: Now my real problem is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140707/retrive-string-out-of-addvalueeventlistener-firebase but sadly so many question but not a single real or full solution. The problem is created by asynchronous nature of listeners....

Comment: I have done nested listeners and it works, if you add the variable outside of the second listener you will get null, this `String fullname=dataSnapshot.child("full_name").getValue().toString();` is working, it is this `comment1.setUsername(fullname);` that is not working

Comment: thanks. By the way sorry for the wording above. I meant in that link I sent there are so many questions but not a single real solution. 
Yes that line is working. But setusername done inside second listeners will obviously won't work and it is like ajax refresh and value is lost and no relation between defined out the second listener and first listeners. So I need someway to get that fullname outside the second event listener. Even I tried it as a global variable, didn't work.

Comment: because it is asychronous, it wont work adding it outside of the second listener you will get null there for sure. But why is `setUsername` not working inside the second listener if retrieving `fullname` is working