# Setting an integer value in textView shows null, How to solve this in android?

Tags: java, android

I fetched a value from database and stored in a variable. I exactly got the expected value. But when I try to set those value into a textview it shows null or 0. Why this happening? How to solve this?

I used,

```
 claimedNos = dataSnapshot.child("Claimed").getValue(int.class);
```

this code for getting data from database.

```
 valueClaimed.setText(String.valueOf(claimedNos));
```

this for setting value to textview.

code is here,

```
public int claimedNos;

      uDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           claimedNos = dataSnapshot.child("Claimed").getValue(Integer.class);
            Log.d("TAG","claimed nos in account  :"+claimedNos);
        }
```

Comment: valueClaimed.setText(claimedNos+""); , if claimedNos contains value .

Comment: post the error message from your console

Comment: @PraveenRawat no way. Shows zero itself

Comment: Try with `Integer.toString(claimedNos)` instead of `String.valueOf...`.

Comment: @Rai_Gaurav no error message, shows zero..

Comment: may be possible you integer value is null integer, you can not convert it null to string,

Comment: @farhana CLAIMED NOS   :3 (Log value)

Comment: @Zelig63 still zero

Comment: Could you please post the code where you retrieve data and set into text view?

Comment: @ManishJain question edited..  
claimed nos in account  :3 (Log value)

Comment: Check this following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140707/retrive-string-out-of-addvalueeventlistener-firebase/42141541)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code posted and comments makes me assuming that you are not setting text into TextView inside listener. So I suggest you to put

```
valueClaimed.setText(String.valueOf(claimedNos));
```

inside `onDataChange` method like this

```
 public int claimedNos=0;

    uDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           claimedNos = dataSnapshot.child("Claimed").getValue(Integer.class);
            Log.d("TAG","claimed nos in account  :"+claimedNos);
           valueClaimed.setText(String.valueOf(claimedNos));
        }
```

Your code is setting value before listner listen dataChange event and it was making null and zero so now above code will set **claimedNos** after receiving it from firebase,