# Kotlin Firebase read child of child data

Tags: android, firebase

Hi I have some issue with calling firebase data from the server.

I can call the single child of data but if I call a nasty child of data(ex: multiple branch of child data), It is not working on kotlin side.

I used ".child()" function on Swift side by just adding ".child()" afterward and it worked on IOS side but I do not understand why the kotlin is not working like that.

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? I've been searching this problem many days but nobody has a clear solution[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITj1O.png)

Comment: Can you please share you code to help you? :-)

Comment: @GSepetadelis Hi I cant put the code here. It says too long

Comment: @Dwwon Lee Please upload a photo from your database

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is of synchronous values, basically onDataChange is called on a different thread.. long story short try calling `sectionRecyclerView.adapter` line inside the for loop that or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140707/retrieve-string-out-of-addvalueeventlistener-firebase) will do the trick.

Comment: Hi so you mean that .child() fun is correct but I need to take care onDataChange in a different way right?
@Mihir Shah

Comment: @DowonLee not exactly child() is correct, the issue is that the fetching is executed in a different thread, so first try logging the values of user inside the for  loop and that will help you get the issue. Then try assigning SectionAdapter inside the for loop that will give you a better understanding of the situation.